# Fast API + Apache Airflow in Docker

Tags: python, docker, airflow, fastapi

I want to build micro-service where I will have two docker containers - Fast API and Apache Airflow. So, my question is how I will able submit some new DAG from some Fast API endpoint ? I guess it should be Airflow CLI ? or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Airflow can be managed via a [REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html) and [CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html).

However, DAGs are Python files and these must be stored on a filesystem accessible by Airflow. There is no way to submit DAG scripts via an API.

There are different ways to deploy DAGs. Since you're working with containers, two options are mounting a volume to which you write your DAG files, or building an image with the DAG scripts built into the image and redeploy Airflow.